# Access: Can only populate text boxes with first 2 columns using [List Name].Column(N)

Tags: ms-access

In Access 2007 I have the Row Source of a List Box set to a query with 5 Columns.  As well as a text box attempting to reference each of those columns based on the list box selection.  [List Name].Column(0) & [List Name].Column(1) work perfectly, columns 2 - 4 do not.

Set each text box equal to column 0 or 1 to confirm there weren't any setting specific to the text box inhibiting it and it would display 0 or 1.

I've been researching what each of the List Box Property settings do and tweaking those and nothing is resolving.  Below are the properties set to currently.

[image]

The query "UP Query" has 5 items in the select statement and I'm able to view it without any issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: Check the "All" tab and the column count.

Comment: That did it, thank you!!!!

Comment: Hi can you please mark my answer as accepted. tnx. saves people from checking answered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the "All" tab and the column count and make sure it matches the number of columns in the query.